# delete file called ".html"

Tags: php, file-io, unlink

I accidentally created a file with no name `http://website.com/myFolder/.html`,

now, in the control panel of my webhost, this file is not listed, I cannot see or delete it...

but I can see it using this **"myList.php"** file: (`http://website.com/myFolder/myList.php`):

```
<?php
echo "<ol>";
if ($handle = opendir('.')) {
    while (false !== ($entry = readdir($handle))) {
        if ($entry != "." && $entry != "..") {
            echo '<li><a href="'.$entry.'" target="_blank">'.$entry.'</a></li>';
        }
    }
    closedir($handle);
}
echo "</ol>";
?>
```

This **"myList.php"** file outputs all the files present in the directory: `http://website.com/folder/`
also the file with no name `http://website.com/myFolder/.html`

How can I delete this file?

I tried to create another .php file called `http://website.com/myFolder/myDelete.php`,
and use the php function **unlink()**:

```
<?php

$path = "../myFolder/.html";
if(file_exists($path)){
    if (is_file($path)){
        //unlink($path);
        if (!unlink($file)){
            echo ("Error deleting".$path);
        }else{
            echo ("Deleted".$path);
        }
    }
}

?>
```

But it doesn't work.

Comment: Can you see `.htaccess` files?

Comment: try to select show dot file option before opening file manager, if you are using cPanel.

Comment: My first guess is your server is Linux and is hiding it since hidden files start with a period.  Can you login with an FTP manager and specify it to show hidden files?  If so, you should be able to delete it that way.

Comment: `$file` is completely undefined in your `myDelete.php` script, so you're REALLY trying to delete something which doesn't exist.

Comment: There is probably some checkbox in your control panel file manager to show hidden files. If there isn't, find one that doesn't suck.

Comment: @Boann LOL yes man xD

Answer (score 1):

```
$path = "../myFolder/.html";
if(file_exists($path)){
    if (is_file($path)){
        //unlink($path);
        if (!unlink($file)){
                    ^^^^^----undefined variable
```

Why all of that when you could just have

```
unlink('.html');
```

? Your unwanted file is in the same directory as your `myDelete.php` script, so the rest of all that is pointless.

Answer (score 0):

Files and directories that begin with `.` are considered "hidden" on *nix systems. You can see them with `ls -la` but not with just `ls`.

Try changing the `$file` variable to just be the name of the file ".html". Make sure to use the `$file` variable for the delete - this is not defined in your example.

```
$file = ".html";

if ( file_exists( $file ) ){
    if ( ! unlink( $file ) ){
        echo "Error deleting '$file'" );
    } else{
        echo "Deleted '$file'";
    }
} else {
    echo "File '$file' does not exist!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The one comment suggested you use FTP, you should have FTP access to your server then you can simply delete through FTP.